# Unable to automate and click on cart to goto checkout page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the below exercise using Selenium web driver with Python. I got stuck at the fourth point using [this demo](http://automationpractice.com/index.php).

How do I locate which element to be used to go to checkout page when there are complex class names and no locators are visible clearly?

1. Login to the application
2. Selecting a product category from Top Menu
3. Selecting a product and adding it to the cart
4. Go to checkout page to provide personal details and complete the order
5. Verify details from final Confirmation page.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


   driver = webdriver.Chrome()

   driver.get("Http://automationpractice.com/")

   driver.find_element_by_class_name('login').click()

   element = driver.find_element_by_id('email')

   username = "**PUT UR EMAIL ID HERE**"

   element.send_keys(username)

   element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

   element = driver.find_element_by_name('passwd')

   password = "**ANY PW**"

   element.send_keys(password)

   element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

   driver.find_element_by_class_name('sf-with-ul').click()

   driver.find_element_by_class_name('img').click()

   driver.find_element_by_class_name('color_pick').click()

   driver.implicitly_wait(5)

   driver.find_element_by_id('add_to_cart').click()

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span").click()
   ```

This is the code I have written for the exercise, but I cannot go to the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **text** property of **span** element for locating **Proceed to checkout** link. Hence, using following **xpath**, you should be able to click on **Proceed to checkout** link:

```
//span[normalize-space(text())='Proceed to checkout']
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

**UPDATE 1:** Replace last line of the code you shared (i.e. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span").click()`) with following and let me know, if it works for you.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(text())='Proceed to checkout']").click()
```

Comment: For your reference i have added the code i have written and hope that will clarify where i m stuck.Thanks.

Comment: Refer to 'UPDATE 1:' in my answer and let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: I tried this, it adds to the cart. Its not proceeding to checkout. Its opening a popup window which shows the product has been added to the cart and has two options continue shopping and proceed to checkout. But it gets stuck that popup and doesn't select proceed to checkout button. So nothing changed after replacing the last line. thanks once again.